# Onedrive authrization link not opening from Ubuntu 19.04 terminal

Tags: sync

After installing Onedrive and running it it showed me the authorization link which opens in browser, when I click on the link nothing happens. It doesn't take me anywhere and when I copy the link into the browser, it shows login page and when I log in there is only blank page, due to this I am unable to use ondrive. I would really any help as I am new to the Linux scene and have zero experience.